# What it a good way set width and height in css3, scss or compass?

Tags: css, sass

I set width and height same time often, so I wrote like this.

`@mixin size($width,$height){width:$width + px; height:$height + px;}`

Is there better way to do it?

I thought there is a default mixin like this, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Is something actually wrong with that mixin?

Comment: I think this is a very basic function(mixin), I want to know if there is already same function is provided in some library or something like that. But "size" is very common word so that I can find only little information by Google.

Comment: No one would write such a mixin because it offers nothing over writing out the properties by hand.  In fact, this mixin is worse than writing it out by hand because it is less clear and just as much typing.

Comment: You're better off creating your own `_mixins` file that you can use across various projects. This would be a great one to include. And no, it doesn't look like there's a library to handle this. It's trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the `+ px`. Doing so will give your mixin more flexibility:

```
@mixin size($width, $height) {
  width: $width; 
  height: $height;
}
```

Then, when using the mixin, you can specify various units such as pixels, em's, percentages, etc:

```
#element {
  @include size(50%, 100px);
}
```

[**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEpvL)